# Checking if child nodes has any img tag in it using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently I am working on transforming QTI to XHTML using XSLT.

I have one tags which may have some html tags. Currently in following example i am having following QTI xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assessmentItem xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1 http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1.xsd" identifier="choice" title="Item Title will come here" adaptive="false" timeDependent="false" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <responseDeclaration identifier="RESPONSE" cardinality="single" baseType="identifier">
    <correctResponse>
      <value>D</value>
    </correctResponse>
  </responseDeclaration>
  <outcomeDeclaration identifier="SCORE" cardinality="single" baseType="integer">
    <defaultValue>
      <value>0</value>
    </defaultValue>
  </outcomeDeclaration>
  <itemBody>
    <div id="item">
      <choiceInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE" shuffle="false" maxChoices="1">
        <prompt>Question text appears here?</prompt>
        <simpleChoice identifier="A">
          <img src="a.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img0" alt=""></img>
        </simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="B">
          <img src="b.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img1" alt=""></img>
        </simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="C">
          <img src="c.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img2" alt=""></img>
        </simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="D">
          <img src="d.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img3" alt=""></img>
        </simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="E">
          <img src="e.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img4" alt=""></img>
        </simpleChoice>
      </choiceInteraction>
    </div>
  </itemBody>
  <responseProcessing template="http://www.imsglobal.org/question/qti_v2p1/rptemplates/match_correct" />
</assessmentItem>
```

I want to check if the simpleChoice tag has any img tag as a child node then I want to add style to the `<div class='content'>` output tag as below, if the simpleChoice tag is not having img tag as a child node i want to skip style attribute to the `<div class='content'>` output tag.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="item">
        <div id="qtn">Question text appears here?</div>
        <div id="inx">
          <div id="ih1">
            <div id="mc1">
              <label id="l1">A.</label>
              <div class="content" style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block'>
                <img src="a.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img0" alt=""/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="ih2">
            <div id="mc2">
              <label id="l2">B.</label>
              <div class="content" style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block'>
                <img src="b.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img1" alt=""/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="ih3">
            <div id="mc3">
              <label id="l3">C.</label>
              <div class="content" style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block'>
                <img src="c.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img2" alt=""/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="ih4">
            <div id="mc4">
              <label id="l4">D.</label>
              <div class="content" style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block'>
                <img src="d.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img3" alt=""/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="ih5">
            <div id="mc5">
              <label id="l5">E.</label>
              <div class="content" style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block'>
                <img src="e.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img4" alt=""/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When matching simpleChoice elements, try including a filter in your xpath.  For instance,

```
simpleChoice      <!-- matches a simpleChoice element -->
simpleChoice[img] <!-- matches a simpleChoice element with a child img element -->
```

You can use this with templates, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            </head>
            <body>
                ((etc, etc, etc, skipping a bit here for brevity; jumping right
                into the simpleChoice items))
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//simpleChoice" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches all other simpleChoice items that are not matched above. -->
    <xsl:template match="simpleChoice">
        <div class="content">
            <xsl:value-of select="@identifier" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This matches simpleChoice items with an img as a direct child -->
    <xsl:template match="simpleChoice[img]">
        <div class="content" style="your style goes here">
            <xsl:value-of select="@identifier" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Live example here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=9r).

---

### Edit

To catch images that may be deeply nested under a `simpleChoice` block, you need to search the *descendant* axis.  This is quite a simple modification.  In my example, change this line:

```
<xsl:template match="simpleChoice[img]">
```

To this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="simpleChoice[descendant::img]">
```

[Here is an updated example](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=9u).  You can read more about xpath axes [here](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts).

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply.

Actually i need to check whether simpleChoice has any img tag node. It could not be the first node within that.

`<div id="ih3">
            <div id="mc3">
              <label id="l3">C.</label>
              <div class="content" style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block'>
                <p> Some text before image </p>
                <p><img src="c.gif" height="75px" width="75px" id="img2" alt=""/></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>`

It is failing in above scenario. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: No problem! Try using the descendant axis, as I have indicated in my edit.  Let me know if you have any further issues!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<xsl:attribute>` inside a literal result element, as long as you do so before adding any child elements, so something like this would work:

```
<xsl:template match="simpleChoice">
  <div class="content">
    <xsl:if test="img">
      <xsl:attribute name="style">vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- rest of the div content goes here -->
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```